# Image file size is too small. I want it increased

Tags: bash, jpeg

Is there a way to pad or "decompress" an image (JPEG) in bash? By this I mean, if the image size is 1.5MB I want it padded up to 5MB, for example. The resultant quality of the image is not (so) important. And if this padding leaves a black rectangle by the side of the image it is acceptable.

EDIT:
THe sole answer below guessed correctly that it was an XY problem.

Comment: It might help to know why you want to do this. It's common to want to increase the displayed size of a jpg; I can't think of a reason to want to increase the file size.

Comment: Because the system I am working on renames and slightly compresses images fed into it. But for some images the resultant image is just a black screen. SO I thought the reason was that these images are too small.

Comment: So you took a wild guess at what was causing your problem and asked about that, rather than telling us what the real problem is and asking how to solve that. This is a classic example of an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). Not a good approach.

Comment: Tell us about the system you're working on and *how* it "slightly compresses images". There's probably something wrong there.

Comment: I see you've accepted my answer -- but I still have no idea what the real problem was. Future readers might benefit from more information.

Comment: You correctly guessed that it was an XY problem. My base problem has nothing to do with resizing bitmaps.

Comment: If you can describe what the actual problem was, and the solution, it would be much more helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick experiment indicates that just appending zero bytes to a `*.jpg` image file still allows it to be viewed.

On Unix, I used a command like this:

```
( cat original.jpg ; dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=1024 ) > bigger.jpg
```

I suspect that any arbitrary data, not just zeros, would have the same result.

(Using an image editor to append a black rectangle to an image probably wouldn't increase the file size by much; compression works really well on blocks of solid color.)

I can hardly imagine a good reason to do this, though.

**Update :**

Based on your comment, this answers the question you asked, but almost certainly won't address your actual problem. You haven't given us enough information to guess how to do that.

This is a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/167210).